# Overflow: hidden; для 100% ширины

Tags: html, css

Добрый день!

Верстается сайт для мобильных ...

Ширина окна по дефолту 100%; Необходимо внутри расположить резиновый блок, но при этом, содержимое блока должно обрезаться, если не входит в экран и должна присутствовать возможность прокрутки touch'ем.

Насколько я понимаю, должно как-то работать с помощью overflow-x: auto; Но как?

Реально ли это реализовать на css?

Если одним CSS не обойтись, прошу подсказать пути решения данной задачи.

Спасибо.

Comment: в смысле хочется прокручивать, но чтобы бегунка не было ? element.scrollTop и element.scrollLeft вам понадобятся из js наверное. [только webkit](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/nZpNT/)

Comment: Да, именно так. На сколько я знаю, на мобильных бегунок не отображается ... или?

Comment: я в мобильниках не силен, но раз вам подойдет, то должно работать как я нарисовал.

Comment: Спасибо, проверю вечерком.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение:

```css
.content-scroll {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-scroll">
  <div class="content">
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
</div>
```